# Angular *ngFor Array of Objects returning [ERROR: Cannot find a differ supporting object]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I am trying to display in HTML a list of data as follows:

**Home.ts**:

```
this.key = 0
objects = {} // The correct setting was objects = [] thanks!

snapshot.forEach(doc => {

          this.objects[this.key] = {
            firstname: doc.id,
            lastname: doc.data().lastname,
            age: doc.data().age
          }

          this.key=this.key+1;
        }
```

This results in the following when displayed in JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.objects));

// RESULT OF THE CONSOLE:

{
 "0":
    {
        "firstname":"james",
        "lastname":"bond",
        "age":"87"
    },

 "1":
    {
        "firstname":"alex",
        "lastname":"tali",
        "age":"59"
    }
 }
```

Now when i use:

```
console.log(this.objects[0].firstname);

// The Result displays:
james
```

Which is the correct behavior!
However when trying to display the list in HTML using the *ngFor it is giving me the Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object.

Here is my code in **Home.html HTML/IONIC**:

```
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4>First Name</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>Last Name</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>Age</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let firstname of objects; let i = index">{{ objects[i].firstname }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let lastname of objects; let i = index">{{ objects[i].lastname }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let age of objects; let i = index">{{ objects[i].age }}</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Any how I can implement the above correctly? logically it should be working just fine! as similar console.log gives a correct result.
While doing a LOT of research i stumbled upon this topic: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392

Which to be honest I'm nor sure if it fits my problem or not.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your first item is not an array, even if you name the keys 0-n. {} Is an object (not used in ngfor) and [] is an array (what you use in an ngfor).

Comment: Yes that was the solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says objects should be an **`array`** of objects, according to your JSON its an object of objects. you need to have proper JSON array, or convert to array of objects.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.global.objects));
```

Comment: How is it possible to convert it to to array of objects?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360863/javascript-converting-object-of-objects-to-array-of-objects

Comment: @JamesAnd: do `this.objects = Object.values(this.objects);`

Comment: @Sajeetharan Angular compiled by Typescript includes es6 polyfills no? I've just tested in on Firefox and it worked.  Actually, according to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), it works on versions of Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera and Safai

Comment: I'm testing it directly on android using ionic cordova run android

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks a lot man!!! It was actually that simple! I had defined objects as: objects = {} now I changed it to objects = [] and it worked beautifully!!!

Comment: @JamesAnd so what's the verdict? does `Object.values` work for you? By the way don't forget to select the answer that helped you

Comment: @BeetleJuice  simply changing objects to objects = [] instead of objects = {} !!!!