# Angular - Displaying Object within Object in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to use angular ngFor to parse this data:

Link: https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/3MvuMn4CESuvA89bfA1cT8mgC4JtKaReku

I'm able to retrieve the data fine by subscribing to it, but when I try to display attributes that has an object in it. I receive [object, Object].

How I am currently attempting this

```
<div *ngFor="let t of transactions" >
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title></mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">From</th>
            <th scope="col">To</th>
            <th scope="col">Receiver</th>
            <th scope="col">Hash</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{t.inputs}}</td>
            <td>-></td>
            <td>{{t.out}}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

component.ts

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  address = "3MvuMn4CESuvA89bfA1cT8mgC4JtKaReku";
  transactions: any ;
  inputs: any;
  public arrayOfKeys
  constructor(private blockchain: BlockchainService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.address)
  }

  getTransactions(){
    this.blockchain.getTransactions().subscribe((data) => {
      this.transactions = data["txs"]
      console.log(this.transactions)
      console.log(this.transactions['inputs'])

    });
  }
}
```

A simple test with console.log to see if this.transactions['inputs'] gives me an undefined

New attempt below. It's closer to working but not fully there yet.

```
<div *ngFor="let t of transactions">
    <div *ngFor="let field of t.inputs ; let i = index">
        <p>{{ field.sequence }}</p>
        <p>{{ field.witness}}</p>
        {{i}}
        {{field.prev_out[i].addr}}
        <hr>
        <div *ngFor="let out of field.prev_out">
          {{out.addr}}
          </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The error it gives me

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Comment: share your component.ts codes also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular \*ngFor Array of Objects returning \[ERROR: Cannot find a differ supporting object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230070/angular-ngfor-array-of-objects-returning-error-cannot-find-a-differ-supportin)

Answer (score 0):

Because `inputs` and `out` are objects. You would have to do `{{ t.inputs.fieldYouWant }}` to get a certain field of the `input` object.

If you want the entire `input` you would have to store it in your component and do an `ngFor` on that.

I'm not sure if you can do something like this but you can try it out:

```
<div *ngFor="let t of transactions">
     <div *ngFor="let field of t.inputs">
         {{ field }}
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, its because the `t.inputs` and `t.out` are objects and not string. If you want to just show the plain text data then you can use "json" filter of anuglarjs or convert these values in string using "JSON.stringify"

Using angularjs json filter -

```
<pre>{{ {'name':'value'} | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: It's tagged as `angular` I'm not sure if this works in angular

Comment: @VincentNguyen  yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

The t.inputs is not an object, it is an array of object. So I think this should work.

```
<div *ngFor="let t of transactions">
<div *ngFor="let field of t.inputs ; let i = index">
    <p>{{ field.sequence }}</p>
    <p>{{ field.witness}}</p>
    {{i}}
    <hr>
    {{field.prev_outt.addr}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this works for inputs. But im trying to also access the object "prev_out" within the input property. Specfically the "addr". I tried inputting another ngFor within the loops to access the prev_out object it but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: No idea why he just copy/pasted my answer but... are you sure another `<div *ngFor="let out of field.prev_out> doesn't work? @tenkdarko

Comment: @VincentNguyen yes, I updated with the code I'm currently using. Please give feedback. ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: @tenkdarko That error means you cannot iterate `prev_out` because it is not an array. It is an object. I would recommend you store `prev_out` in your `component.ts` as a variable and iterate that variable in the template it would be cleaner and easier.

Comment: `transactions` and `transaction.inputs` are both arrays of objects

Answer (score 0):

A simple test with console.log to see if this.transactions['inputs'] gives me an undefined

**Quick Solution**
if you are getting the date in console instead of undefined than the approach of getting the data might be wrong. The data object in `getTransactions()` is of undefined type. Instead of `t.out`, assign value to a variable `resp` by writing `t['out']`, giving complete name eg `['inputs']['0']['sequence']` in your component. Than use `resp` in component.html

**Solution**

Cast the result data by defining `interface` for json and than use `.` to access the values