# Convert object of objects to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following data structure:

```
const data = {
    school1:{location:'medway',score:6},
    school2:{location:'milan',score:8},
    school3:{location:'brooklyn',score:103,
    }
```

How can I convert it to the following format in javascript:

```
const data = [
    {name:'school1', location:'medway',score:6},
    {name:'school2', location:'milan',score:8},
    {name:'school3', location:'brooklyn',score:103}
    ]
```

Comment: `Object.entries(data).map(([k,v]) => ({name:k,...v}))`

Comment: every answer looks the same as the comment,,,,

Comment: @ChrisG i was too lazy atm to write an answer

Comment: @cmgchess more like other ppl too lazy to come up with a different method

Comment: @ChrisG i think this one is a common question that's why many came up with same answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Converting Object of Objects to Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360863/javascript-converting-object-of-objects-to-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the entries of the object.

```js
const data={school1:{location:"medway",score:6},school2:{location:"milan",score:8},school3:{location:"brooklyn",score:103}};
const res = Object.entries(data).map(([name, v]) => ({name, ...v}));
console.log(res);
```